# Ruby Exception - If Statement rescue doesn't handling exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rescue

I everyone, I've some issue to handling exception in ruby. I doesn't understand why my statement doesn't work.

Error : Couldn't find User with id=14
I want to redirect to the login page.

```
 def login_required
    begin
      if session[:user_id] == nil
        redirect_to login_path, :notice => "You are not logged"
      elsif  User.find(session[:user_id])
        return nil
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to login_path, :notice => "No user corresponding in database"
    end
  end
```

Hope you can help me.

Cordially,
Aubin

Comment: Unrelated, but IMO returning `nil` here is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def login_required
  begin
  if session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, :notice => "You are not logged"
  elsif  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).nil?
    #rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (use if u want to use User.find)
    redirect_to login_path, :notice => "No user corresponding in database"
    return nil
  end

end
```

end

Comment: This code doesn't work. I still have de exception : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#index - Couldn't find User with id=14. I don't know how handling this exception..

Comment: if you are using User.find in index action of TasksController then use User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) as shown above.

Comment: Did you know why find_by_id not handling exception RecordNotFound ?

Comment: find_by_id silently returns nil. it doesnot raises an exception when a record is not found, as find do.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this to not work is that ActiveRecord is actually finding a row

```
User.find(session[:user_id])
```

Try logging the session[:user_id] and looking into DB using SQL.

On another note, you can use

```
session[:user_id].nil?
```

instead of

```
session[:user_id] == nil
```

Comment: In SQL select * from users where id = 15 return nothing. And with my code ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#index - Couldn't find User with id=14. Thx for the nil tips.

Comment: so what is in your TasksController#index
can you provide that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your method as follows:

```
def login_required

 return redirect_to(login_path, 
   :notice => "You are not logged") if session[:user_id].blank?

 user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
 return user if user.present?
 redirect_to login_path, :notice => "No user corresponding in database" 
end
```